# Copying the rows within the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-update, inner-join

I need to move what's been appended at the end of my table to its very beginning, however
the same record is being copied into destination.

In other words, between the ids 1 and 3567 I only have the record from the id 3567 repeated until the end. I believe that my outer and even inner sub-query lacks something ?

Thanks for the hint

Query:

```
  UPDATE dbo.TABLE
  SET Xwgs = dt.Xwgs, Ywgs = dt.Ywgs
  FROM 
     (
        SELECT
            Xwgs,
            Ywgs
        FROM dbo.TABLE
        WHERE 
            Id BETWEEN 3567 AND 7243
     ) dt
  WHERE
    Id BETWEEN 1 AND 3566
```

Comment: I don't understand. There is a row with ID 1 and a row with ID 3567 in your table and you want to copy the values from row 3567 to row 1? Andf the same for 2/3568, 3/3569, etc.? Can't you just delete the rows with the lower IDs, so as to only keep the good rows?

Comment: it's the easiest way handling data imported from the excel sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
update t
set xwgs = dt.xwgs, ywgs = dt.ywgs
from mytable t
inner join (
    select xwgs, ywgs
    from mytable
    where id between 3567 and 7243
) dt
on t.id = dt.id - 3566
```

The main difference with your query is that it properly correlates the target table and the derived table.

Note that this does not actually *move* the rows; all it does is copy the values from the upper bucket to the corresponding value in the lower bucket.

Comment: Shouldn't the t1 be dt ?

Answer (score 0):

You know that You can always sort Your table with `ORDER BY id DESC` right?

Sometimes its needed do something strange. I do it like that:

1. Copy the whole table into a temp table (it may be #temporary table)
2. Drop or Truncate or Delete records from that table
3. Insert those records again from my temp table
4. Drop temp table

But an UPDATE is also a solution.

**Tip:** You can allow inserting values into identity (autoincreament) `id` column with [`SET IDENTITY_INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
SELECT *
INTO tmp__MyTable -- this will create a new table
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY id

DELETE FROM dbo.MyTable -- will throw an error on foreign keys conflicts

INSERT INTO MyTable (col,col2) -- column list here
SELECT col,col2
FROM tmp__MyTable
ORDER BY id DESC
-- or something like that: 
-- ORDER BY CASE WHEN id <= 3566 THEN -id ELSE id END

-- DROP TABLE tmp__MyTable
```